# $request->request-all() returns empty array in symfony3

Tags: php, twig, symfony

there are some simply task and take me crazy, I've searched around sites an the solutions i've found not work or I've some not configured correctly in my enviroonment.

Well, i've a simple form in html, the form have his name (accessForm) and his inputs too, there are the form's code

```
<form action="admin#updateProfile" method="post" role="form" name="accessForm" class="smart-form">
                        <header>
                            Datos de acceso a la red
                        </header>
                        {% if error != '0' %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                            <strong>Hay algún error<br/></strong> {{ error }}
                            </div>                                  
                        {% endif %}
                        <fieldset>

                            <section>
                                <label class="label">Nombre de usuario</label>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="25" name="nombreUsuario" value="{{ userData.username }}">
                                </label>
                                <div class="note">
                                    <strong>Nombre de usuario:</strong> es el nombre con el que puedes loguearte en la red SEMB, si cambias este dato, tu sesión finalizará automáticamente y tendrás que volver a loguearte.
                                </div>
                            </section>

                            <section>
                                <label class="label">Contraseña</label>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="password" maxlength="50" name="password">
                                </label>
                                <div class="note">
                                    <strong>Tu contraseña de acceso:</strong> deja este campo en blanco si no quieres cambiar tu contraseña. Si la cambias, tu sesión finalizará y tendrás que volver a loguearte.
                                </div>
                            </section>

                            <section>
                                <label class="label">Correo electrónico</label>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="80" name="email" value= "{{ userData.email }}">
                                </label>
                                <div class="note">
                                    <strong>Correo electrónico:</strong> es fundamental que sea un correo válido ya que ahí recibirás las notificaciones (si quieres claro), también puedes usar el e-mail para loguearte en la red.
                                </div>
                            </section>  

                            <section>
                                <label class="toggle">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="recibirNotificaciones" {{ userData.recibirNotificaciones }}>
                                    <i data-swchon-text="SI" data-swchoff-text="NO"></i> deseo recibir notificaciones por e-mail
                                </label>
                            </section>      
                        </fieldset>

                        <header>
                            Configuración de apariencia
                        </header>

                        <fieldset>
                            <section>
                                <label class="label">Fondo para el perfil de usuario</label>
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <img id="background" src="../img/backgrounds/{{ userData.background }}" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <label class="label">Cambiar fondo</label>
                                <label for="file" class="input input-file">
                                    <div class="button"><input id="imgBackground" type="file" name="backgroundFile" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value">Cargar</div><input type="text" placeholder="Selecciona un fichero desde tu ordenador" readonly="">
                                </label>
                            </section>


                            <section>
                                <label class="label">Avatar</label>
                                <div class="profile-pic">
                                    <img id="avatar" src="../img/avatars/{{ userData.avatar }}" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <label class="label">Cambiar avatar</label>
                                <label for="file" class="input input-file">
                                    <div class="button"><input id="imgAvatar" type="file" name="avatarFile" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value">Cargar</div><input type="text" placeholder="Selecciona un fichero desde tu ordenador" readonly="">
                                </label>
                            </section>

                        </fieldset>

                        <footer>
                            <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Guardar cambios
                            </button>

                        </footer>
                    </form>
```

This form is POST method and action calls to a route. This route aims to a controller, in the action of this controller, I've put a simple variable to get the value of $request.

```
  public function UpdateProfileAction(Request $request)
{
    $error = "0";

    $data = $request->request->all();
```

Well, $request->request-all() ALWAYS returns empty array

What are wrong in my Form?

NOTE: If I change the form method to GET, the $data variable in controller returns array correctly (change the attribute request by query instead)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your controller file for creating that form above? Or did you just create a twig file like that? Something doesn't seem right.

Comment: @AlvinBunk there's nothing wrong with not using Symfony's Form Component. Mario, it seems to be  working fine for me.

Comment: Alvin Bunk, the form is embedeed in the twig template, i'ts a piece of html. I use a bootsrap generic template. This form haven't a class (ej "userType") and don't use symfony's form component to create it.

Comment: @dragoste, working fine for you?, i'ts something wrong in my local server?, any php configuration wrong?.... i've really crazy with this case.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. I would just go through the code with xdebug. That would take a few minutes to figure it out. Also check Symfony's profiler it if shows POST variables.

Comment: Yes, I use xdebug and in a breakpoint in the controller just after $data variable, and $data retuns "array [0]".... something is wrong in my enviroonment, i'm sure. Thanks @dragoste, if I found a solution, i post it. Couriusly, if the form passed with GET method, i catch the array without problems..... rare rare rare.

Comment: You could also check the browser debug tools to see what data is actually sent to the server

Comment: Thanks @emanueloster, I check this too and I post the conclusions i've found, in few hours I try....